# Which css element to edit to properly format Wordpress post teasers

Tags: css, wordpress, post

I'm fairly certain this question hasn't been answered before. I just took over managing a website and I'm a fairly novice programmer so I would like some advice on which element or elements would be best change in order to fix the problem of post teaser text over running other elements. My thought was to strictly define the image size so that even if the feature image is smaller the height of the post remains the same and the words will fit in. (I could limit the words of course, but when the picture is smaller - less words fit) I'm still struggling to learn css positioning (it seems so simple but nothing seems to turn out like I expect) So I wanted to ask before making any changes.

This is the kind of category page that is causing me problems
http://everydayambassador.org/category/field-notes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css file:

```
header.page-header{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.hentry{
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.entry-content{
    margin: 0 0 3em;
}
```

The thing is, this is kinda badly styled. Ideally you'd put `overflow: hidden` to your post container, so that nothing 'flows' out of it, but your author name, date etc. are absolutely positioned, so you can't do that (if you did that, you couldn't put them where they are at the moment).

If you're using Firefox, use web developer extension, and in Chrome you can use inspect option (F12, or right click and inspect element option). There you can see what element to target. You can even try out to change things (paddings etc.), to see what's changing, and how, before you write it in css file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought that it might be badly styled, that's why I really wanted to get some advice before playing with it because I was afraid things wouldn't react as expected because it was set up in a strange way. Thank you so much

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you! Now I just need to make sure I understand why! :o)

Comment: It's actually easy if you use Chrome's inspector. You see the divs, and their properties (mainly it's about positioning and margins and or paddings). There are lots of info about it online, I like http://css-tricks.com/ it's a great site for info on css :) Feel free to accept the answer (click the checkmark under my answer) if you want :D